# JSON_2_Region.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Tags: android, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing the mobile application using ADT there and I am facing error

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

while my code reads from the path `testapp/assets/www/Pages/JSON_2_Region.json`

Here is my code:

```
  $.getJSON('JSON_2_Region.json', function (data) {
                $('#List_Region_Details').empty();
                $('#JSON_2_Region li').remove();
                region_list = data.JSON_MAS_Data_Region;                                                            

                $.each(region_list, function (index, JSON_MAS_Data_Region) {
                    $('#List_Region_Details').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + JSON_MAS_Data_Region.Region_ID + '">' + JSON_MAS_Data_Region.Region_Name + '</a></li>');
                });

                $('#List_Region_Details').listview('refresh');
            });
```

The error happens only in the Chrome browser when I copy/paste the url seperately but works fine in my ADT default browser and emulator.

Comment: Why did you put the tag cordova if nowhere in your question you mention using it?

Comment: If I understand your question, you're trying to access a file on your computer from your browser, which is not allowed by secutity restrictions of the browser unless you explicitly disable security settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to testing using your browser, you need to use ripple chrome extension to run in mobile environment. You will got this error message if you not run the app in mobile environment.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
```

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en